# Shocked O3 pool system with calcium hypochlorte, but free chlorine at 0. Is this expected? Cause for concern?

Tags: pool, maintenance

My understanding is that swimming pool water should be kept at around 1-3ppm free chlorine level. However 1.5 days after shocking small 2000 gallon pool with 2 pounds of 56% calcium hypochlorite (good for 2600 gallons) the chlorine level to my surprise is at 0.

Should I still try to raise chlorine level or is this completely expected as Ozone "eats" away chlorine?

The pool shock was success as water is crystal clear from algae now, but I am just concerned of non existent chlorine. The cyanuric acid was high at 300 ppm too.

Comment: Chlorine level cannot be maintained when acid level is high.

Comment: Is one of your measurements off a decimal point? That's a large amount of shock for a 2,000 gallon pool.